# Python AIOHTTP.web server multiprocessing load-balancer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, load-balancing, aiohttp

I am currently developing a web app using the aiohttp module. I'm using:

`aiohttp.web`, `asyncio`, `uvloop`, `aiohttp_session`, `aiohttp_security`, `aiomysql`, and `aioredis`

I have run some benchmarks against it and while they're pretty good, I can't help but want for more. I know that Python is, by nature, single-threaded. AIOHTTP is using async as to be non-blocking but am I correct in assuming that it is not utilizing all CPU cores?

**My idea:** Run multiple instances of my aiohttp.web code via `concurrent.futures` in multiprocessing mode. Each process would serve the site on a different port. I would then put a load balancer in front of them. MySQL and Redis can be used to share state where necessary such as for sessions.

**Question:** Given a server with several CPU cores, will this result in the desired performance increase? If so, is there any specific pattern to pursue in order to avert problems? I can't think of anything that these aio modules are doing that would require that there only be a single thread though I could be wrong.

**Note:** This is not a subjective question as I've posed it. Either the module is currently bound to one thread/process or it isn't - can benefit from a multiprocessing module + load balancer or can't.

Comment: Do you need to use `concurrent.futures`? Why not use gunicorn or any other tool that simplifies running several application instances?

Comment: Why not use `gunicorn` with some async workers like `uvicorn`?

Comment: I really like what gelonida did in their answer because it uses a really clean port-sharing feature of Linux and does not depend on external apps to work. A deprecated AIOHTTP feature was used though which prompted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719022/aiohttp-application-make-handler-is-deprecated-adding-multiprocessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right asyncio uses one CPU only. (one event loop uses one thread only and thus one CPU only)

Whether your whole project is network or CPU bound is something I can't say.
You have to try.

You could use nginx or haproxy as load balancer.

You might even try to use no load balancer at all. I never tried this feature for load balancing, just as proof of concept for a fail-over system. 
With new kernels multiple processes can listen to the same port (when using the `SO_REUSEPORT` option) and I guess it's the kernel who would be doing a round robin.

Here a small link to an article comparing performance of a typical nginx configuration vs an nginx setup with the `SO_REUSEPORT` feature:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-sad-state-of-linux-socket-balancing/

It seems `SO_REUSEPORT` might distributes the CPU charge rather evenly, but might increase the variation of response times. Not sure this is relevant in your setup, but thought I let you know.

**Added 2020-02-04:**

My solution added 2019-12-09 works, but triggers a deprecation warning.

When having more time and time for testing it myself I will post the improved solution here. For the time being you can find it at [AIOHTTP - Application.make_handler(...) is deprecated - Adding Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719022/aiohttp-application-make-handler-is-deprecated-adding-multiprocessing)

**Added 2019-12-09:**

Here a small example of an HTTP server, that can be started multiple times listening on the same socket.
The kernel would distribute the tasks. I never checked whether this is efficient or not though.

**reuseport.py:**

```
import asyncio
import os
import socket
import time
from aiohttp import web


def mk_socket(host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reuseport=False):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    if reuseport:
        SO_REUSEPORT = 15
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    return sock

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    pid = os.getpid()
    text = "{:.2f}: Hello {}! Process {} is treating you\n".format(
        time.time(), name, pid)
    time.sleep(0.5)  # intentionally blocking sleep to simulate CPU load
    return web.Response(text=text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port=8000
    reuseport = True
    app = web.Application()
    sock = mk_socket(host, port, reuseport=reuseport)
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                    web.get('/{name}', handle)])
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(
        protocol_factory=app.make_handler(),
        sock=sock,
        )
    srv = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.run_forever()
```

And one way to test it:

```
./reuseport.py & ./reuseport.py & 
sleep 2 # sleep a little so servers are up
for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ; do wget -q http://localhost:8000/$n -O - & done
```

The output might look like:

```
1575887410.91: Hello 1! Process 12635 is treating you
1575887410.91: Hello 2! Process 12633 is treating you
1575887411.42: Hello 5! Process 12633 is treating you
1575887410.92: Hello 7! Process 12634 is treating you
1575887411.42: Hello 6! Process 12634 is treating you
1575887411.92: Hello 4! Process 12634 is treating you
1575887412.42: Hello 3! Process 12634 is treating you
1575887412.92: Hello 8! Process 12634 is treating you
```

Comment: How can multiple processes listen to the same port? Wouldn't each need its own port?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. New Linux kernels allow multiple processes to listen on the same port if opened with a specific option. It's of course only one process who will be used for one incoming connection. It's kind of a kernel built in load balancing.

Comment: What's it called? I can't find any info on it. It would be cool but it's not that important because in aiohttp, I could use a separate port for each process. There's no major downside to doing that.

Comment: @xendi I enhanced my answer. The option is SO_REUSEPORT

Comment: This is great but there is a deprecated warning: `DeprecationWarning: Application.make_handler(...) is deprecated, use AppRunner API instead
  protocol_factory=app.make_handler(),`. Can you fix it and I will accept?

Comment: It would also be better to use concurrent.futures - ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: I have successfully applied ProcessPoolExecutor. When I tried to switch to AppRunner, I ran into a problem.

Comment: thanks. Will look into it ASAP. Will need it anyway also for our code snippet.
Am just a little overloaded at work and privatly the last few days.

If somebody finds a cleaned solution before me I'll be happy if not will look into it.

Comment: Still have not figured it out yet. BTW, this code increased performance from around 7k requests-per-second to 27,000.

Comment: Added new bounty.

Comment: Deprecation has been fixed! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719022/aiohttp-application-make-handler-is-deprecated-adding-multiprocessing Maybe add that link in the answer for people to see. I accepted your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot xendi for posting here. It's great to know that my answer put you in the right direction. will add the link.

Comment: Xendi, Just for info. I enhanced the answer slightly. I found a link looking at the performance of my suggested `SO_REUSEPORT` solution.

I think it's an interesting read. perhaps it encourages you to try out with nginx and compare the performance. If I understood well the average latency should be quite similiar though the latency distribution seems to be worse with  `SO_REUSEPORT`

Comment: Thanks. For that, I use a different evented server (openlitespeed) which is just as fast if not faster and certainly easier to configure (Drop-in replacement for apache). The benchmarks I've been running are raw aiohttp. I just inspected them with and without SO_REUSEPORT. The results actually show SO_REUSEPORT decreasing the per-thread latency average from 1.04s (Consider I have mysql going on) to 280ms. I haven't tested with litespeed or nginx yet but I know that adding litespeed doesn't hurt the requests/sec. Will have to see about latency.

Comment: BTW when I say I put lsws in front of aiohttp, I don't mean I'm using it for multiprocessing. It's just a security precaution and helps with caching. The solution in this answer and its sister question are extremely performant. I think we have no reason to rely on nginx or otherwise for multiprocessing anymore. It's still advised to put a server in front of aiohttp as mentioned before, only for security.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to not reinvent the wheel and use one of the proposed solutions at the documentation:
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html#nginx-supervisord

Comment: gelonida's solution is awesome. He managed to get multiprocessing working sharing the same port without the need for something like nginx. I already run a web server in front of my apps but spawning multiple processes from the shell across multiple ports is somewhat dubious compared to his solution. He used a deprecated feature of aiohttp though which should be replaced. I opened the bounty for the purpose of fixing the deprecated code (See comments up there)